# twisted IBodyProducer don't work with unicode

Tags: twisted

I use [offical example](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/stringprod.py) to sends unicode string:

```
agent.request('POST',"http://localhost:8088/order", Headers({'Content-Type': ['application/json']}), StringProducer("{u'aaa':1}"))
```

but it don't work, I gets nothing on server side:

```
class FormPage(Resource):
    def render_POST(self, request):
        json_str = request.content.read()
        print json_str

root = Resource()
root.putChild("order", FormPage())
factory = Site(root)
reactor.listenTCP(8088, factory)
reactor.run()
```

How to made it?

Comment: computer will not feel which number is "unusual", it just a number.

Comment: Of course I write a server listen on 8088 and print what its get

Comment: `"{u'aaa':1}"` is not a unicode string.

Comment: That's my fault, but StringProducer(u"aaa") don't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intentional.  HTTP bodies are bytes, not text.  If you want to return text for JSON, encode the JSON as UTF-8 (the default encoding, specified in the standard, and the only one you should use).

That's also not the only problem with your code: `u` prefixes and single quotes are Python syntax, not JSON.  Instead, do this:

```
agent.request('POST',"http://localhost:8088/order",
              Headers({'Content-Type': ['application/json']}), 
              StringProducer(u"{"aaa": 1}".encode("utf-8"))
```

That ought to work.

Comment: encode('utf-8') will return bytes in 2.x? how StringProducer knows it is a str or str but implicit bytes. because 2.x has no bytes type, it still is str. I think after encode, the data in str was transformed into a series of ascii characters. So the I/O in python can read/write byte by byte, does it?

Comment: Yes, `encode("utf-8")` returns bytes on 2.x.  2.x does have a `bytes` type, it's an alias for the `str` type.